# Counting rows by the different date

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column of dates and a column of items.

Hi Everyone
I want to count the number of items for a certain date, how many of them are per day.
Column 1 Date - Column 2 - Items

```
01.09.2009  IT004  
01.09.2009  IT004
01.09.2009  IT005
01.09.2009  IT006
01.09.2009  IT006
01.09.2009  IT006
06.09.2009  IT004
06.09.2009  IT004
06.09.2009  IT005
07.09.2009  IT004
07.09.2009  IT005
07.09.2009  IT005
07.09.2009  IT006
```

---

```
              01.09.2009   06.09.2009   07.09.2009
For It004         2            2             1
For It005         1            1             2
For It006         3            0             1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and many thanks in advance.

Atanas

Answer (score 1):

If that's all the table has, this should work:

```
SELECT datecol, count(*) FROM table GROUP BY datecol
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Pivot Table to do this.**

Use Items as Row Field.

Use Date as Column and Data Field (Count of Date).

**Using VBA**

Assuming that Items and Date are in worksheet "Sheet1" starting in cell A1, the pivot table is created in a worksheet "Sheet2" starting in cell A3 in the active workbook.

```
Sub createPivotTableReport()

  Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  Set wsReport = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

  Set rngData = wsData.UsedRange
  Set rngReport = wsReport.Range("a3")

  Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, rngData.Address(True, True, 1, True))
  Set pvtTable = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(rngReport)

  pvtFieldsRow = Array("Items")
  pvtFieldsCol = Array("Date")

  pvtTable.AddFields pvtFieldsRow, pvtFieldsCol
  pvtTable.PivotFields("Date").Orientation = xlDataField

End Sub
```

**Note:**

In some (newer?) versions of Excel, the line

```
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, rngData.Address(True, True, 1, True))
```

can be changed to

```
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(xlDatabase, rngData)
```

Or maybe my old version of Excel is just bad. I don't know.

I also posted a .vbs solution here:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/ScriptCenter/en-us/dde1e5e2-f5f6-4053-84fb-b820f01f1fdf

Answer (score 0):

How about using Excel's DCOUNTA function?  Have two tables, where the top table is the criteria for the DSUM function.

EX)

```
Date         Items
01.09.2009   IT004

Date         Items
01.09.2009   IT004
01.09.2009   IT004
01.09.2009   IT005
```

So on a line below the bottom table, you'd put the DCOUNTA function:

```
=DCOUNTA(A3:B6,"items",A1:B2)
```

Always look for built-in functionality first :)